# utilise atom or sublime text in ubuntu Python Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, sublime-text

As a beginner I initiated python with IDLE: You write a code, than save the file and run with F5.

In the past days I asked how to run scripts. I get good answers as to begin the programm with "#!/path/to/python ". It's good but not for all files e.g. files in /home/myname/Dropbox/programs/python.... are not accessible with this method.
And I want to know how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python code can be compiled and run from Sublime using `Ctrl+B` or `Tools->Build System->Python`. I'm just not sure why the script in your Dropbox folder won't run, have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: with #!/path/to/python  I tested the same file in /home/myname/file.py   when the fil migrated to /home/myname/downloads or any over subdirectory the result is "python: can't open file 'mot_le_plus_frequent2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
" as you see. It is not linked specificaly to dropbox.

Comment: with #!/path/to/python  I tested the same file in /home/myname/file.py   when the fil migrated to /home/myname/downloads or any over subdirectory the result is "python: can't open file 'mot_le_plus_frequent2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
" as you see. It is not linked specificaly to dropbox.  what is file permission??

Comment: @AKounovsky I know the control B patent but I don't like it because when I need to test inputs This is not practical

Comment: File persmissions are the property of files and folders, it ddetermines whether the file can be read, written into or run as a program/script. You can right click on your file, click on Properties and check, if the file can be run as a script since I don't think you're running it from your terminal. Let me ask you a thing: What is your path to python?

Comment: I ame sorry but my knowlege is very lacunare ... What is "path to python". Today I ame in another computer W7, the properties says type: Python File C:/Users/moshel/Dropbox/appren..."learn about access control and permission --> Security Settings Property Page but it is microsoft

Comment: Well, the path to python is a place, where your python executable is located. For example my path to python is `/usr/bin/python` so the first line of that script would be in my case `#!/usr/bin/python`, but since ou can have different version or path, it's safer to use `#!/usr/bin/env python`. That works for linux, off course. If you want to run you python script, I'd suggest reading answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows).

Comment: I tested with #!/usr/bin/env python and.... It's Goood!!! Thank you!

Comment: but strangely with an other script I tried the same yvanmoses@yvanmoses-desktop:~$ python mot_le_plus_frequent.py
python: can't open file 'mot_le_plus_frequent.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
despite the #!/usr/bin/env python in the first line

Comment: Have you tried running it directly from terminal? Open the folder where your script is located and run `python mot_le_plus_frequent.py` and tell me if it works. If it works, the file permissions can still be the problem, if so, try runninch `chmod u+x python mot_le_plus_frequent.py` in the same folder. With this command, you're letting your system know that the user (you) can run it as executable.

Comment: @A.Kounovsty. the very strange adventure continue! In the sublime text with the CTRL + B It's run. I copy the "/home/.../crypto3.py" and past this in the Terminal, it's run too. but if i try python crypto3.py the terminal return: "python: can't open file 'crypto3.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". If I try  with chmod --> 

:~$ chmod u+x python crypto3.py
chmod: impossible d'accéder à «python»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
chmod: impossible d'accéder à «crypto3.py»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type What is chmod?

Comment: Chmod is a tool that's used to change the file permissions, with `u+x` you give that file a permission to be run as a program. Try running it with root priviliges: `sudo chmod u+x your_file.py` and after that try running it directly from your file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Finally The best is to write cd and the whole path.
with the use of the **upper array in terminal**, it is easy to write again the path.
The use of control + B in sublime is less practical, in particular for input() functions.
and in the terminal it is easy for the choice of python version, 2.7 or 3.4.
for ruby too.